# Is there a way to order @Path in Quarkus

Tags: java, rest, resteasy, quarkus, java-ee-8

I currently have a problem similar to [this](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/9200) but in quarkus-resteasy. I have looked around and I cannot find a way to order the paths. The endpoint for `getAllNotifications()` is never selected, all requests go to `getModel()`:

```
@Get
@Path("/cars/{brand}/{model}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getModel(@PathParam("brand") String brand, @PathParam("model") String model) {
  ...
}

@Get
@Path("/cars/notification/all")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getAllNotifications() {
  ...
}
```

Is there a way to prioritize either endpoint 1 or 2 like it was done [here](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/9200)

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30690946/jax-rs-overloading-methods-paths-order-of-execution this should not happen, the second one should have precedence over the first one.

Comment: @luk2302 thank you the update. I have updated the question to match my exact problem. I had a look at your link and looks like it should not happen but it is. These endpoints were working correctly in payara-micro. The problem started after the migration to quarkus.

Comment: This indeed should not happen. If it does, please open an issue in the Quarkus Github repo