# Jersey invoking arbitrary versions of my methods that share the same url

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I have 2 endpoints in Jersey configured for the same URL, but each one generates a different type of data (JSON or CSV).

When a request comes with the header `Accept: application/json` I see `getDataJson` is invoked, and when it comes with `Accept: text/csv` I see `getDataCsv` is invoked.

Nonetheless, when a request comes with `Accept: */*`, I expected one of the methods to be invoked consistently (`getDataJson` if it's the first one) but instead, I have a server where `Accept: */*` always causes `getDataCsv` to be invoked, and another server where `getDataJson` is always the one invoked.

Do you know what could be the reason Jersey's behaviour is not consistent?

```java
    @POST
    @Path("customer/{custId}/search/stuff")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    MyDataResponse getDataJson(@PathParam("custId") UUID custId,
                               SearchParams params);

    @POST
    @Path("customer/{custId}/search/stuff")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces("text/csv")
    Response getDataCsv(@PathParam("custId") UUID custId,
                        SearchParams params);
```

More info:

- I'm using Jersey 2.33
- I already ran `sha256sum` on the jars of my app thinking maybe there was a difference, but they are identical.
- I found some docs [here](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/2.33/user-guide.html), but the section `Procedure 8.2. MessageBodyReader<T> Selection Algorithm` didn't give me the info I wanted

Comment: [Not the cause but possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28107842/2587435)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30691577/2587435