# regular expression in Restwebservices

Tags: java, regex

i am trying to understand rest webservices and came a cross dynamic url building.
below is piece of code i found in examples

```
@Path("/customers")
public class CustomerResource {
@GET
@Path("{id : \\d+}")
public String getCustomer(@PathParam("id") int id) {
...
}
}

@GET
@Path("{id : .+}")
public String getCustomer(@PathParam("id") String id) {
...
}
```

Path attribute is build using regular expression. i tried google and found some info but i am still confused

`{}` is this is used as range like `a{2,3}` means a should be atleast 2 times 
`.+`  is any character at least should occur once
`\d+` at least one digit

but i am unable to imagine which string matches `{id : .+} and {id : \\d+}` can you please help me understand

Comment: As an aside the two path expressions here are ambiguous and the behavior using both of these is undefined for this level of ambiguity (meaning results may differ for different implementations) as [examined here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28103978/2587435)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\d+ means "[any digit](https://www.websense.com/content/support/library/web/hosted/dsc_admin/wildcard_regex.aspx) [one or more times](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html)". Double "\" is used to escape [special character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) "\".

"{id : \d+}" means method param **id must** be only number.

.+ means "[any character](https://www.websense.com/content/support/library/web/hosted/dsc_admin/wildcard_regex.aspx) [one or more times](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html)". Dot symbol is not escaped because it is [not special character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html)

"{id : .+}" means that method param **id can be** any string

Comment: Thanks for response .. so if i understand properly {id:  it is just saying that id is method parameter  name and has nothing to do with regex .. the last part \d+ or .+ is regex which we need to look at

Comment: Yes. Here are more samples: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.19/jax-rs.html#d4e102

Answer (score 0):

if you have any doubt, please refer this following link.
http://java2novice.com/restful-web-services/jax-rs-path-regex-match/

```
you can do like that
@Path("{id: [0-9]+}")
```