# REST API - filters, child entities or is leaking information really so bad?

Tags: rest, restful-url

**The basic problem**

I have a rest API. For the sake of this example, let's say I have users, they can be members in any number of groups, and both users and groups can own objects.

Any user can filter objects by various criteria:

```
/objects?color=green

/objects?created=yesterday
```

but only members of a given group can filter by group ownership:

```
/objects?groupId=1
```

and only the actual user can filter by user ownership:

```
/objects?userId=55
```

There are now two basic patterns - one could make the object a child entity of the group, such as:

```
/groups/4/objects/1
```

with 4 being the group ID and 1 being the object ID. the other option is having group and objects side-by-side:

```
/groups/4
```

and

```
/objects/1
```

making the object a child of the group and/or user would eliminate the other filtering options - essentially, i have one object with multiple paths to it.

**The actual question**

If I want to limit access for a regular user so that he/she can only access objects that are directly owned by him/her or by groups that he/she is a member of, it does work as a filter on the collection - but what about the entity level?

If I try:

```
/objects/9
```

But the object is owned by a group I am not a member of, I would expect an authorization error, while if the object doesn't exist at all, i would expect a "not found" - this, however, would leak information about the book's existence, and I also would have to retrieve the object in order to be able to determine whether or not the user has the right to see it.

So I came up with this:

```
/objects/9?groupId=4
```

or

```
/objects/9?userId=55
```

In this, I can base the initial decision on authorization on the group ID or user ID, and then try to retrieve the object with the additional restriction.

If the user is NOT a member of group `4`, I can say `not authorized`, and if the book doesn't exist, I can say `not found`, meaning not that the object doesn't exist, but that the object doesn't exist in group `4`. This answer is more clear, and also I would not have to retrieve the object first.

The alternative would be to return an authorization error regardless of whether it is due to the fact I am not authorized OR due to the fact that the object doesn't exist. This answer is slightly imprecise, but it would put less of a burden on the caller.

Another possibility would be to map multiple paths:

```
/objects
/groups/4/objects
/users/9/objects
/colors/green/objects
```

This seems rather messy and would violate the principle of having a single path for a single concept.

Does anyone have any practical insight on this? Any reasons (apart from the ones mentioned) why one or the other would be preferable?

Comment: "A single resource MAY be identified by many different URIs" as the HTTP specs state http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correct, every object is linked to (at least) one group or (at least) one user, so you don't have the problem of having an object without a group or user.

If this is the case I don't see the point in using filters as it would not make sense in a REST way and also not give any benefit to the client site.

So as you suggested you could just use the following:

```
/groups/$groupID/objects/$objectID
```

and

```
/user/$userID/objects/$objectID
```

Now you server should check if the client is authorized ("the user a member of the group" / "the current user")  given the `$groupID` xor the `$userID`

- if not authorized: not even check if object is there. Just give the not authorized error.
- if authorized: give standard response codes

I don't see a benefit for a non authorized client to get information if a resource is available or not as its not important for him, because he cant access it either way. And as you suggested it would result in a information leak *which could result in a security problem* (but that is completely depending on your API and what its information and usage).

### Now lets go through the scenarios for group calls:

---

User Arnold (member of groups: 1,2,3) wants to access existing object 7 of the member group 3.

`GET` `/groups/3/objects/7`

**response:** `#200`

---

User Arnold (member of groups: 1,2,3) wants to access non existing object 55 of his member group 2.

`GET`  `/groups/2/objects/55`

**response:** `#404`

---

User Arnold (member of groups: 1,2,3) wants to access existing object 11 of a non member group 5.

`GET` `/groups/5/objects/11`

**response:** `#401`

---

User Arnold (member of groups: 1,2,3) wants to access non existing object 19 of a non member group 5.

`GET` `/groups/5/objects/19`

**response:** `#401`

---

### And for user objects:

---

User Arnold wants to access his non existing object 56.

`GET` `/user/arnold/objects/56`

**response:** `#404`

---

User Arnold wants to access his existing object 13.

`GET` `/user/arnold/objects/13`

**response:** `#200`

---

User Arnold wants to access Jon's existing object 77.

`GET` `/user/jon/objects/77`

**response:** `#401`

---

User Arnold wants to access Jon's non existing object 88.

`GET` `/user/jon/objects/88`

**response:** `#401`

---

As you can see the server just responds with `#401` if the client is non authorzied. Additional it would be great to give a error message in the body e.g. `Sorry, but you are not authorized to see content of user "Jon"` or `Sorry, but you are not authorized to see content of group "ABYZX"`, so the client knows what the problem is.

> This seems rather messy and would violate the principle of having a single path for a single concept.

I don't see it that way as also different sources [(1)](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/restfulresourcenaming.html) [(3)](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.6) and [SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1929347/rest-multiple-uri-for-the-same-resource) say its really no problem to have multiple paths or URIs.

> Each resource in a service suite will have **at least** one URI identifying it.

It could help clients understand the authorization process and with that help them to navigate through your API.

Comment: Hello Robert, I agree with your solution under the limited conditions  ... but I also noticed that my question underemphasized the element of having multiple relationships that could qualify as "parents" - i only had "an administrative user can get the full list" ... which isn't really that clear. I edited my question.

Comment: that would be at least one URL for every criterium relevant to authorization? and it isn't possible to combine them - or at least, it would be rather weird.

Answer (score 0):

Any of the URI choices you describe are fine.  I perfer flat URIs, but it doesn't really matter.

The real question is how to handle unauthorized requests.  In that case, I suggest responding with 404 in all cases including when the resource exists, but the user doesn't have access.  It avoids the information leaking problem and it is completely compatible with the HTTP specification.

This pattern makes sense logically too.  From the perspective of the user with insufficient permissions, the resource doesn't exist.

If you have ever tried to view a private Github project without having permissions to view it, you would have seen this pattern in action.  Github will respond with 404 even if the project actually exists.